# Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: Não é possível obter a propriedade 'style' de referência indefinida ou nula

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estou com esse erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando evitar esse erro usando a verificação abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (document.getElementById('panelActivex') != null) {
        document.getElementById('panelActivex').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('visitorImage').className = 'fld';
    }
});
```

Quando eu compilo o código fica assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('panelActivex').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('visitorImage').className = 'fld';   
});
```

E está dando o erro do print.
Como eu resolvo isso?

Comment: Por que está fazendo `document.getEl...` se está usando jQuery? `$('#panelActivex').css('display', 'none')` é bem mais simples e provavelmente resolve esse problema

Comment: O elemento `panelActivex` existe ou não na página?

Comment: Opa.
Vou testar.
Desculpa mas eu sou não sou bom no Javascript.

Comment: Vou verificar @Sam mas creio que exista sim.

Comment: @Sam. Está dando o mesmo erro.
Já limpei o cache e até reiniciei a máquina.
Eu coloquei a função igualzinha a que vc postou mas quando eu compilo e chega na busca da erro e o código exibido no VS2015 é o antigo, como se eu não tivesse alterado nada.  
**Sabe o que pode estar causando isso?**

Comment: Esse problema do código mudar era Cache.
Resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método `.hide()` do jQuery (já que você está usando `$.ready`) para o elemento `panelActivex` e no elemento `visitorImage` você altera a classe também com jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#panelActivex').hide();
  $('#visitorImage').attr('class', 'fld');
});
```

Isso evita o erro citado porque mesmo que o elemento não exista, o jQuery não retorna o erro de referência nula ou indefinida.